# How to print '*' pattern printing using JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript

I am learning loop in Javascript.

I need output like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

But, When I use this code :

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j = j + 1) {
    console.log('*');
  }
  console.log("");
}
```

I got an output like this :

```
*

*
*

*
*
*

*
*
*
*

*
*
*
*
*
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: each `console.log()` is one line. You don't start a new line by logging `("")` ... So if you want to print `***` you have to use `console.log('***')` and not `console.log('*');console.log('*');console.log('*')` as you are currently doing

Comment: Don't forget to declare your loop variables: `for (let i = 1 ....`

Comment: @georg Ok. I already declared

Comment: @cloned I need to print * as a loop.

Comment: @cloned Not just printing. As a part of learning I need it as loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, every `console.log()` is printed on a new line. So you will have to keep a string which you keep adding to. And then print it:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
  let str = "";
  for (j = 0; j < i; j = j + 1) {
    str += "*";
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a second loop. You can achieve the result by using 1 loop and the [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method.

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i=i+1){
    console.log('*'.repeat(i));
}
```

Edited according to @trincot. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `"*".repeat(i)`... No need to create arrays.

Comment: Also please try and add explanation text, just answering with blocks of code is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

#### Single Loop Solution with String.prototype.repeat()

In JavaScript, `console.log()` prints output on a **new line**, so you need to **[concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) all the stars in a string** and print it.

```js
const printPattern = (count, symbol) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    console.log(symbol.repeat(i));
  }
};

printPattern(5, '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `[...Array(n).keys()]` to get the range 0-4 and then map this range onto different length strings of stars, which you can then join with line breaks.

```
console.log([...Array(5).keys()].map(i => "*".repeat(i + 1)).join("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i = i + 1) {
  let str = "";
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j = j + 1) {
    str += j;
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let rows = 6;
let char = "";

for (let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    char += "*";
  }
  char += "\n";
}
console.log(char);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).